# Easiest way to achieve selectable dropdown menu with only 2 entries? iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to display a short selectable dropdown menu. Only 2 entries. What would be the best way to go about it? I looked at the Picker View but doesn't seem to be good as it's a different view - I would like the options to be displayed directly on the current screen, just like when you see a dropdown menu on a web site.

Also, how would I hook that up with a button click?

Comment: try with tableview with uianimation

Comment: i would recomment to radio buttons for two entries.

Comment: Thank you. I created tableviews. How do I hide-unhide them within the button click's implementation?

Comment: if you using `tableView` just recognize them specifically using tag to hide eg:`tableView.tag = 2` or use `UIAlertController` for small list.

Comment: .tag=2 didn't work. I am using simple "Views". How do I hide-unhide them then?

Answer (score 0):

Try with UIAlertController with type action sheet.

https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/uialertcontroller-alert-action-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

-(void)viewDidLoad{

dropDownButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[dropDownButton addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[dropDownButton setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

dropDownButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

[dropDownButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[view addSubview:dropDownButton];

dropDownTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(button. frame),CGRect​Get​Max​Y(button. frame), button.frame.size.width,88) style:UITableViewStylePlain] ;

// tablewview height is cell height(44) * numberOfRows (arraycount)

dropDownTableView.dataSource = self;

dropDownTableView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:dropDownTableView];

dropDownTableView.hidden = YES;

}

-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
 {

dropDownTableView.hidden = NO;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

  return 1;

  }
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  return 2;

  }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {

  ```
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
  ```

  }

  // Configure the cell...
  cell.textLabel.text = [yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);

[dropDownButton setTitle:[yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

dropDownTableView.hidden = YES;

}

Answer (score 0):

I was in a dilema to choose between UITableView, or ActionSheet. Both of them are good, but I wanted to show a actual drop down in my app. I came across these two GitHub projects, there are cool and easy way to integrate.

https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown

https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKDropdownMenu

They come up with Cocopods as well. Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Great answer by Rajesh Dharani.
I just arranged it more clearly, and for more than 2 entries:

```
UIButton *dropDownButton;
UITableView *dropDownTableView;
NSArray *yourArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    yourArray = @[@"English", @"French", @"German", @"Spanish", @"Hebrew", @"Arabic", @"Persian", @"Finnish", @"Japanese", @"Korean"];

    dropDownButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [dropDownButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [dropDownButton setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    
    dropDownButton.frame = CGRectMake(107.5, 150, 160.0, 40.0);

    [dropDownButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:dropDownButton];

    
//    dropDownTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(button.frame),CGRect​Get​Max​Y(button.frame), button.frame.size.width,88) style:UITableViewStylePlain] ;
    
    dropDownTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,30, 300,500) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    // tablewview height is cell height(44) * numberOfRows (arraycount)

    dropDownTableView.dataSource = (id)self;

    dropDownTableView.delegate = (id)self;

    [self.view addSubview:dropDownTableView];

    dropDownTableView.hidden = YES;

}


- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    dropDownTableView.hidden = NO;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

//     Configure the cell... 
    cell.textLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d", (int)indexPath.row);

    [dropDownButton setTitle:[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    
    dropDownTableView.hidden = YES;

}
```